# Rails: Postgis doesn't create normal columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to make Postgis working in my Rails app. I create a table using migration as below:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.point :location, geographic: true
      t.belongs_to :owner, null: false
      t.string :content
      t.timestamps

      t.index :owner_id
      t.index :location, spatial: true
    end
  end
end
```

After *rake db:migrate*, I checked *schema.rb* file, and it shows:

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.spatial  "location",   limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
add_index "posts", ["location"], :name => "index_posts_on_location", :spatial => true
```

Which means *owner_id* and *content* column does not get created. I further confirmed this by checking DB using *psql*. What am I doing wrong here?

FYI, I'm using Ruby v2.1.5p273, Rails v4.1.8, Postgresql 9.3 w/ Postgis2 from official Postgresql repo. I'm running them on CentOS 7.

**Edit:**

Looks like rake *db:reset* does not do what I expected. If I do *rake db:drop; rake db:create; rake db:migrate*, the schema will be right. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html) helped me out, what I should really do is *rake db:migrate:reset*.

Answer (score 0):

try references instead belongs_to.
 If you use referneces remove t.index :owner_id

Comment: Still the same result.